# Failing to connect to Integration Service with SSMS on one VDI but on another it works fine

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssis, sql-server-2017

I have two VDIs with the exact same version of SSMS installed. On one, I can log into the standalone Integration Service of a remote server running SQL Server 2017, on the other I cannot.
[image: SSMS Error message]

Every single other online result is not helpful, the usual culprit is not having the right version of SSMS or permissions set up on the remote server but that is not the case here. I also can't just use SSISDB because I need to grab packages from the Integration service itself, and also I want to make sure this error doesn't mean there's general problems with the VDI's setup.

The ONLY difference between the two copies of SSMS are the version of the Microsoft Data Access component and the OS Version.

If Anyone's encountered this specific case where a working Integration Service that can be connected to without issues won't work on a new machine please share what was wrong. Apparently the Firewall settings on the new VDI are correct but I'm not so sure myself. I don't have access to change them however.

Comment: No insight from me on using the Integration Services management nodule but there's nothing that UI does that you can't do with the command line [dtutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: So both VDIs are trying to connect to the same single SSIS server, one can connect but the other can't?

Comment: Yep, it's very annoying. I Can work around it to get access to what I need, but I'd rather fix the core problem.